# Calculating average in array under different conditions using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose following data frame:

| COND1 | COND2 | COND3 | COND4 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 0.3 | 44 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 50 | 0.2 | 55 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 200 | 1.5 | 91 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | -50 | 1.8 | 18 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 30 | -0.5 | 52 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | -85 | 0.1 | 84 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 42 | 0.01 | 44 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 86 | -0.4 | 18 |

I want to export average value for column A, B and C when:

1. COND1 is 1 & COND2 is 1
2. COND1 is 1 & COND2 is 2
3. COND1 is 2 & COND2 is 1
4. COND1 is 2 & COND2 is 2

This is very straight forward using excel filters but I want to know if there is faster way to get the same results using python pandas.

Comment: Use `c = ['A','B','C']`  `df[c] = df.groupby(['COND1','COND2'])[c].transform('mean`)`

Comment: @jezrael ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: with `transform` ?

Comment: happened while doing this
df[c] = df.groupby(['COND1','COND2'])

Comment: not understand, my solution failed? Or uses part of solution, so it is expected failed?

Comment: @jezrael "Length of values (25) does not match length of index (3125)" there seems to be a problem in my data frame

Comment: Is possible missing values in `COND1, COND2` ?